# Which is the proper use of an age group: 65 years OR older or 65 years AND older

Tags: phrase-usage

For use in scientific journals: Is it "more correct" to use the phrase "65 years or older" to describe an age group or "65 years and older".

Comment: Either. One looks at the 'qualifying' age of an individual within the group, the other at the qualifying ages group members will have. They boil down to the same thing. // But 'aged 65 and above' perhaps sounds more clinical.

Comment: Hello, Cromarty! Both are correct. The difference is that the one with "and" describes ("the set of all people 65 years **and** older, inclusive"), and the other describes (the set of everyone who is in "the set of 65-year-olds" **or** in the set of "older than 65-year-olds), which coincide exactly. Is one of them the preferred format in similar papers in the same journal as the one you are working with? Welcome to EL&U. Cheers!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, although I would say that when referring to study groups "65 and older" is probably more appropriate. I feel that "65 or older" is more appropriate for referring to people who qualify (or perhaps fail to qualify) for something, For example "We looked at the activity levels of club members aged 65 _and_ over" as against "Members aged 65 _or_ over are eligible for the Senior Citizen's discount on their membership fees"

Answer (score 1):

Both phrases are used, and two others, too:

- 65 and over,
- 65 and above.